# Browser notifications

Tags: javascript, php, notifications

How can I notify a user every x time without waiting for the user to be on my page?

I tested with `push.js`, but I do not know how to do it.

[image: info]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from ur question, you want to give the Gmail type notification on the browser also you are not using NPM / or don't know how to use it.

How to do it in pure JavaScript:

Step 1.
You first need your user to be on your site and ask him for permission for future notification even if he is not on the site.

If the user gives you the permission. Then every time he keeps your application open in the browser. You can fire a notification function (eg in the link) when needed.

the following Link Explains how you do so.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission